# Segmentation Fault with Libvlc on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, libvlc

I am using the exact same code as [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/). I just replaced the file reading part with this:
 char* filename = "testVLC.mpg";
 media = libvlc_media_new_path(vlcInstance, filename);

I get a segmentation fault at the second line above. The video file is in the same folder as the cpp file. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use libvlc v2.2 - you have to use slightly modified `libvlc` tree ([I have one prepared](https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/releases/download/v.0.1.3/libvlc_2.2.1_mac.zip), please extract it from command line, to preserve symlinks)

The problem is libvlc v2.2 has a bug which leads to load `libvlccore` by plugins from wrong place

Comment: So, I keep the original vlc install, extract this one. Do i place it somewhere specific, or do I have to reinstall the whole thing?

Comment: you should place it near your executable or .dylib which calls `libvlc_new`

Comment: Ok, I thought there was something wrong with my libvlc install and so I started the install all over again. But now it won't install. I think I broke it. I'll try to fix it and then try your solution. Thanks a lot though.